# intellij sbt "autoimport" and "source for SBT and Plugins" are missing in Import project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Ok so I have a project which works perfectly on my Windows intellij and I would like to do the same on my Ubuntu Intellij, the scala plugin is install on both, however some options when I import the project are missing (and they are essential for my project to work)

[The good import options on my windows intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0G5X.jpg)

[The bad import on Linux intellij options despite the fact they both have the Scala plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdwoV.jpg)

I would like to get the "use auto import" and "sources for SBT and Plugins" to come back

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using different versions of the Scala plugin on both. In the 2017.1 release, the autoimport option has been removed, and the "SBT sources and plugins" option has been renamed to just "SBT sources".

The autoimport option has been restored in the current Nightly build of the Scala plugin and will be in the next bugfix update as well.

Comment: Thank you I will try to downgrade for now so